# How to draw 2D racing tracks using vector graphics?

Tags: unity, 2d, rendering

See this [game](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5lJuEW-5vr8&t=6s). 
[image]

I am trying to build a similar one using Unity. However, I am not sure how to build the scene, specifically, the walls.  Unity 2D allows me to create Sprite, but what kind of sprite should I use? Or I am on the wrong direction?

Answer (score 1):

I found a pretty good example http://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/top-down-car, which uses Box2D.

To create the track, one creates a subclass of a `world` class and populates it with a pre-defined world, stored in a file, usually a json file. To create such a file, one can use Box2D's world editor. A good editor is [R.U.B.E](https://www.iforce2d.net/rube/), another is Epic-World-box2d-editor(search github). I haven't tried either but according to their doc, they are what I am looking for.

As for how to render the simulation from a top-down view, one can define the world to be zero-gravity. Then, to drive the car forward or backward, just give the car a positive or negative velocity in `y` direction, respectively. To drive the car left or right, give the car a positive or negative velocity in `x` direction, respectively. One can apply fictions too.